# how to send a mail when workflow not triggered at given time in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange, informatica-data-integration-hub

I have a workflow which gets triggered everyday in the Morning at 07:15 AM.I want to get an email to my Id from Informatica when the workflow doesn't get trigerred within 3 min from the start time.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options -

1. easiest would be - create another workflow(scheduled at 7:18 AM) with a command task which will check a file.
   After command task, put a condition to the task link status=1 and then add a email task.
   Add a touch command as pre session to the main workflow.
   New workflow will be like -

```
start -->cmd task -->|--link status<>0--> email task
```

command task will be like -

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -r /somedir/ind.txt ]; then
  exit 0
  rm /somedir/ind.txt
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Now, in real time, at 7:15 the wkflow will start and crete the file, second workflow will detect and do nothing. Now , if file doenst exist, it will mail.

2. second option will be, you can create a cron script that starts around 7:18AM, check if file exist or not - if file is absent, it will mail and delete the file. Your command file should be like this -

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -r /somedir/ind.txt ]; then
  exit 0
  rm /somedir/ind.txt
  mail -s <...some command...>
else
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: i want to get an email to my ID automatically when workflow not start at schedule time.

Comment: Either of above options should work